# Prove that a plane is continuous?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Okay, so the problem gives a matrix:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&2\\
3&4}
$$
and this matrix is an $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ linear map. I am asked to explicitly write the component functions of $A$, and prove that $A$ is continuous. I am guessing that writing these 2 functions out explicitly is a hint, so I have to prove that these 2 functions are continuous. But these 2 functions are planes, and so I have to use the "neighborhood version" of the epsilon-delta proof for limits, but we've never done anything like this before so I'm not sure how to approach the proof since it's not like an epsilon-delta proof with only a single variable.

Comment: The matrix is equal with the function $f(x,y)=(x+2y,3x+4y)$. Proving the continuity now would be easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so writing it out, we have
$$
Ax = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 + 2 x_2\\ 3x_1 + 4x_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you already noticed that you are left to show that $x_1 + 2 x_2$ and $3x_1 + 4x_2$ are continuous functions. So in order to show this in the first case, for example, pick some $\varepsilon >0$ and now look for $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y$, $||x-y|| < \delta $ implies $|x_1 + 2 x_2 - y_1 -2y_2| < \varepsilon$. This is just the definition of continuity. To find such a $\delta$, you should notice that $||x-y|| < \delta $ already implies that $|x_1 - y_1| < \delta $ and $|x_2 - y_2| < \delta $ ... Now the rest should be easy ;-)

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first exposure to these types of proofs so nothing is obvious to me at the moment. Why did you use $||x-y||< \delta$? The definition I learned is $|x-a|< \delta$ but I don't know how to represent that in more than one variable. Is that what the notation $||x-y||$ is for? For the $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$ part I understand because the (first) function is $x_1+2x_2$, and we want to take the limit at the point when it's continuous so you just plug in the variable $y$ into the function. I don't notice why $||x-y||< \delta$ implies $|x_1-y_1|< \delta$ and $|x_2-y_2|< \delta $. :-(

Comment: Well, a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x = (x_1, x_2)$ if for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y = (y_1, y_2)$, the condition $||x-y|| < \delta $ implies |$f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. Here ||_|| denotes the vector norm, i.e. $||(z_1, z_2)|| =\sqrt{z_1^2 + z_2^2}$. Now just replace $z$ by $x-y$.